# Insert Image link with datatype image in SQL Server database with node js

Tags: node.js, sql-server, image

I am using SQL Server 2014. I'm saving the image by converting it to arrayBuffer. Here's my code

```
let image = await axios.get('http://image.png', {responseType: 'arraybuffer'});
let data = JSON.stringify(image.data)
//My query
`INSERT INTO Image (ImageData) VALUES (${data})`
```

Here's the response: maxlength 128. Is there another options on how to save image link?

Thank you, I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @marc_s Thank you! I already changed the data type but now my problem is how to save the image coming from a link like `https://res.cloudinary.com/carchie/image/upload/v1586855324/sample.jpg`. They used `OPENROWSET` for saving an image but the image is in a file path.